# Webpack watch is not updating bundle.js file

Tags: typescript, webpack

When using webpack watch, bundle.js is correctly updated in output directory which is "wwwroot" of my mvc application. After file edit, it reacts to change, console output is generated but bundle.js is not updated. On second file change, it stucks on "Checking started in a separate process...". Deleting repo and cloning again seems to work for a while. After few file changes, it is doing again.

In webpack i am using babel, awesome-tzpescript-loader , extract-text-webpack-plugin, some style loaders with modules.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in distiction between .js and .ts files. Why ?

On project build, Visual Studio compiles typescript files into .js and .js.map. This is totally unecessary, because webpack handles typescript files as well (with awesome-typescript-loader). When editing componet .tsx files in Visual Studio Code or With disabled compileOnSave option in tsconfig.json, edited ts file is not recompiled and my webpack was processing unactual .js file.

In result, no changes was detected and bundle.js file was not updated.

Solution was to disable compiling typescript files in visual studio on project build. Add

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

in PropertyGroup of your .csproj.